# I cannot understand API docs for Java/Android?

Tags: java, android

Consider the following code snippet for reading a file in Java/Android:

```
FileInputStream fis = openFileInput("myfile.txt");
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer();
while (bis.available()!=0) {
    char c = (char) bis.read();
    b.append(c);
}
bis.close();
fis.close();
```

I am talking about available() method in the condition of while loop. I looked the API documentation for that method and I have the following questions:

- How the iteration inside the the while loop is happening, i.e. how is the file pointer moving to another chunk of data during each iteration of while loop? This is not specified in the API documentation.
- How can I figure out which method of which class should I use to accomplish a task?

Comment: Your question is too broad. We can't help you understand all Javadoc everywhere. If you question is just about understanding that piece of code, then remove half your words and ensure that's the sole subject.

Comment: Also, note that using `available()` to determine when reading should finish is not recommended. It doesn't tell you how many bytes are left in the stream, it just advises on how many could be read without blocking. This sort of code can cause you to read fewer bytes than there is in the file.

Comment: API docs don't usually carry much information like this. You would be much better off looking for a tutorial on the web. API docs are normally used just as a reference guide.

Answer (score 4):

The **available** method returns an int as an estimate of the number of bytes that can be read (or skipped over) from this input stream without blocking by the next invocation of a method for this input stream.

That `while loop` is iterating till the end of the file essentially, when there is no bytes there is no file.

Here is some documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html

Answer (score 1):

The bis.available functions checks for end of file. in each iteration of the while loop when u do bis.read() the file pointer reads one character and automatically moves on to the next one.

As far as your query about which method to use. just look up the parameters that the function takes. and what u need to accomplish. its not very difficult figuring that out.